# FastAPI OAuth2PasswordRequestForm dependency causing request failure

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, jwt, fastapi

I'm using the auth scheme detailed in FastAPI's [user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/#update-the-token-path-operation) (JWT/Bearer token). When I try to get a token from the `/token` endpoint the request fails before the path operation function ever runs. Here's the function in question:

```
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), session: SessionLocal = Depends(get_db)):
    user = authenticate_user(session, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": user.id})
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

I normally use breakpoints to help figure out what's going wrong in these situations, but the call fails before any code in the function actually runs, leading me to believe the problem is with the `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` dependency. I verified that this was the problem by disabling the `form_data parameter` and was able to execute the full request.

The errors I'm getting are pretty sparse on details. Here's what I'm getting in the console: `INFO:     127.0.0.1:52261 - "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request`

And here's what I see in the Swagger UI:

[image]

This was working for me in the single-file format used in the tutorial, but I've since broken things out into different files to keep my larger project organized. I have a feeling that I just missed something somewhere along the line while reorganizing this code but can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course the solution to this issue was in [the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/first-steps/). The problem was that I was missing the `python-multipart` dependency. I just ran `pip install python-multipart` and restarted my server and then I was able to authenticate.

Comment: I have already installed this but still have the very same issue! any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

in [the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/first-steps/#create-mainpy), you have to provide the login token path for OAuth2PasswordBearer

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
```

in case your are breaking your app into different modules, where your endpoint paths begins with a prefix, include the prefix. so it looks like this:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/prefix/token")
```

Comment: The prefix detail fixed it for me. Also, you may need to create a [johndoe](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#authenticate) instance to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set response_model to token after you have created a token schema like this:

```
class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str
```

so your code should look like this

`@router.post('/token', response_body=Token)`

Comment: it should be response_model= Token